# For each item in list of classes

Tags: c#, list, enumerable

I'm fairly sure this question has been asked before, but I'm unsure what to search for, so if there is something already been asked for this, please direct me there.

Usually, I would do something like this

```
List<string> values = new List<string>();
foreach (MyClass workingClass in AllTheClasses)
{
    string val = workingClass.SomeField);
    values.Add(val);
}
```

However, I would like to use something like this :

```
List<string> values = AllTheClasses.ToList(SomeField);
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Any problem with `AllTheClasses.Select(c=>c.SomeField).ToList()` ?

Comment: Is AllTheClasses a List?

Comment: @mshsayem, thats exactly what I needed, thank you very much. Do you want me to mark that as an answer?

Comment: @Hey24sheep, yes. Its a List<MyClass>

Comment: Use linq as suggested by @mshsayem

Comment: Apart from LINQ's `ToList()` most containers have a constructor that accepts an `IEnumerable<T>` as input that copies the enumerable's contents into the container. Some also have an `AddRange` method that allows adding an IEnumerable<T> to an existing container

Comment: @HimBromBeere the question wants to return field values in a list, not the entire class

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Linq the way:

```
var values = AllTheClasses.Select(c=>c.SomeField).ToList();
```